# Set Bootstrap Panel Size 100% + Highcharts content

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm working to show Graphs with Highcharts library in three Television.

The Resolution is FULL HD (1920 x 1080) for all televisions.

I have one Bootstrap Panel with Graph in `panel-body`.

```
<div class="panel panel-blue">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw fa-2x">Graph 1</i>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="graph1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the Graph adjust with `Width` and i want adjust `height` is `100%` dynamically, like 'FULLSCREEN'
I can set the graphic `height` and `width` in Highcharts as

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'graph1',
    type: 'bar',
    events: {},
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
},
```

But this don't work correctly.. 
Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use percents in value in CSS:

```
#graph1 {
  height:100%;
}
```

considering `.panel-body` has fixed height.

And then if you have to provide height in points, do:

```
var graphHeight = $('#graph1').height()

//or

var graphHeight = document.getElementById('graph1').clientHeight;

chart: {
    renderTo: 'graph1',
    type: 'bar',
    events: {},
    width: 1920,
    height: graphHeight,
},
```

Comment: @user2227682, sorry mistyped, I meant in CSS ofc.